# Hibernate @Size Validator

Tags: java, hibernate, validation

I have spring mvc application that has a form with a first name field. This field should be at least 3 characters of more. I am using the hibernate @Size validator as follows in my backing bean class:

```
@Size(min=3, message="message.key")
String firstName;
```

When this validation fails, the appropriate error message is displayed. However, when the page reloads after the failure, the value entered for first name is cleared from the input field. How do I get that value to remain in the field for editing? If possible....

Code is as follows:

JSP Snippet - Not this is portlet application

```
<portlet:renderURL var="createUserAction">
    <portlet:param name="action" value="createUser"/>
</portlet:renderURL>
<form:form method="post" commandName="userInformation" action="${createUserAction}" htmlEscape="false">
<h2>
    <fmt:message key="msg.label.form.title" bundle="${msg}" />
</h2>
<form:errors path="*" cssClass="errorblock" element="div"></form:errors>
<p>
    <form:label path="firstName">
        <fmt:message key="msg.label.form.fname" bundle="${msg}"/>
    </form:label>
   <form:input path="firstName" />
</p>
<p>
    <form:label path="lastName">
        <fmt:message key="msg.label.form.lname" bundle="${msg}"/>
    </form:label>
    <form:input path="lastName" />
</p>
<div style="margin-left: 150px; margin-top: 20px">
    <input type="submit" value="Save" /> 
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
</div>
</form:form>
```

Bean

```
@Component
public class UserInformation {


  @NotEmpty(message="msg.error.required.lname")
  private String lastName;

  @NotEmpty(message="msg.error.required.fname")
  @Size(min=3, message="msg.error.length.fname")
  private String firstName;

  public UserInformation() {
    super();
  }

  public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
  }

  public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }

  public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
  }

  public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
  }
```

}

Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("VIEW")
public class UserManagement {

  @Autowired
  private UserInformation userInformation;

  @Autowired
  private Validator validator;

  @Autowired
  private MessageSource messageSource;

  @RequestMapping(params="page=addUser")
  public String addUser(Model model){
    userInformation = new UserInformation();
    model.addAttribute("userInformation", userInformation); 
    return Page.ADD_USER;
  }

  @RequestMapping(params="action=createUser")
  public String createUser(
   @ModelAttribute(value="userInformation") UserInformation userInformation,
   BindingResult result, Model model) throws ApplicationException{

    // get values
    String firstName = userInformation.getFirstName();

    System.out.println("fname="+firstName);

    Set<ConstraintViolation<UserInformation>> constraintViolations = 
     validator.validate(userInformation);

   for(ConstraintViolation<UserInformation> constraintViolation : constraintViolations) {
     String propertyPath = constraintViolation.getPropertyPath().toString();
     String message = constraintViolation.getMessage();
     result.addError(
       new FieldError(
         "member", 
         propertyPath, 
         messageSource.getMessage(
           message, 
           null, 
           Locale.ENGLISH
         )
       )
     );
  }
  // Errors found
  if(result.hasErrors()){
    return UMConstants.Page.ADD_USER;
  }

  String successMsg = messageSource.getMessage(
    "msg.user.added", 
    new Object[]{userInformation.getFirstName()}, 
    Locale.ENGLISH
   );

   model.addAttribute("successMsg", successMsg);

   return UMConstants.Page.INDEX;
  }
}
```

The user would click a link that executes the **addUser** method to load the page with the form, indicated by the JSP snippet above. When the user clicks the submit button, the **createUser** method is called. This is where the validations are done.

Comment: get the value from request and set the value again to request.

Comment: Thanks. Could you show me an example? I am to print the value to the logs, but i'm uncertain as to how I would set the value to the request.

Comment: can you add your codes that you are referring

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I found the solution by (painfully) iterating through the Spring MVC `form:input` jsp  tag's source code... Thought I would share it here, maybe it helps someone.

In a nutshell: the problem comes from the `form:input` tag. This tag, when evaluating its value, checks for errors associated with this field (the `path` attribute), and if it finds any, it will use the `rejectedValue` attribute of the `FieldError` instance  instead of the value of the field from the command or form object.

When using the `@Valid` annotation in the controller method's argument, Spring will correctly fill the `rejectedValue` property on the `FieldError` objects.

But if you create the `FieldError` objects manually using the short constructor (3 args) the `rejectedValue` attribute of the `FieldError` will not be set and the tag will use this null value for display...

The solution is to use the long version of the constructor when creating your `FieldError` objects, for example :

```
result.addError(
       new FieldError(
         "member", 
         "firstName", 
         userInformation.getFirstName(),
         false,
         new String[0],
         new Object[0],
         messageSource.getMessage(
           message, 
           null, 
           Locale.ENGLISH
         )
       )
     );
```

The `form:input` tag will use the `rejectedValue` property of the `FieldError`, which is the third argument in this longer constructor, and which was not set when using the simpler 3 args constructor...

Note that the actual value on the command or form object (here userInformation) was always right, which made this bug/quirk pretty hard to track.

Hope that helps someone, eventually...

Answer (score 0):

when error occurred before the return try to add user information to model

```
if(result.hasErrors()){
model.addAttribute("userInformation", userInformation); 
return UMConstants.Page.ADD_USER;
```

}

Updated

I think I figured out your issue. When you have a error you call to addUser method and inside add user method your are creating new UserInformation object and which has no values to display on page. You could try something like below to your addUser method.

```
@RequestMapping(params="page=addUser")
public String addUser(Model model,HttpServletRequest request){
    userInformation =  (UserInformation)request.getAttribute("userInformation");

   if(userInformation == null){
    userInformation = new UserInformation();
   }
    model.addAttribute("userInformation", userInformation); 
    return Page.ADD_USER;
  }
```

Comment: use ModelMap instead of Model in your method signature.

Comment: Wait, **value** is not a valid attribute for the `<form:input>` tag.

Comment: oh oki ignore it and just try to print ${firstName} somwhere in jsp and see whether you can see your first name.

Comment: I didn't add the request parameter, kept the code similar to your initial answer. All I did was to add `<c:out value="${userInformation.firstName}">` to the JSP file and the **firstName** value prints out on the page after validation has failed. However, its still not in the text field as required.

Comment: I think I figured out your issue. When you have a error you call to addUser method and inside add user method your are creating new UserInformation object and which has no values to display on page. You could try something like updated codes to your addUser method.

Comment: I don't think that is the problem. Here's why i say this. If i were to fill in both first name and last name, and the validation only fails for first name, then the value for last name isn't cleared, just the one the one that fails is cleared. So my suspicion is that the validator is the culprit. Maybe i will have to write a custom validator.